# Build errors during C simulation and C synthesis in Vitis unified IDE 2023.2

Tags: opencv, gcc, g++, libgeos

I always keep landing into a build error when I tried to create an RTL IP core from the existing GTM L1 example given [here](https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis_Libraries/tree/main/vision/L1/examples/globaltonemapping). The build error is as shown here: [Undefined reference error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFwDW.png)

The error occurs for both C simulation and synthesis. Build system settings: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Vitis Unified IDE 2023.2, OpenCV 4.4.0 (installed from source as per instructions given [here](https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis_Libraries/tree/master/vision#opencv-installation-guidance)).

Workflow: Created a workspace folder and created an HLS Component specifying gtm_accel as top function. Cloned the Vitis_Libraries repositories and copied the corresponding design and testbench source files into the workspace. Specified the ldflags menu in the C simulation settings with: -*L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_videoio*. Later I changed this path to: *-L/home/alen/repo/OpenCV/install -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc*. Both didn't work.The CFLAGS path is set to:*I/home/alen/repo/Vitis_Libraries/vision/L1 -std=c++0x -I/home/alen/repo/OpenCV/install*.

I double checked the opencv installation and it seems to be fine. What is the cause of this issue? How to fix this?